# Running multiple T4 Templates with a single click

Tags: visual-studio, t4

I have some 6 T4 templates spread through my solution in different projects, is it possible to run them all with a single click or do I necessarily need to go through them one by one?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Does the "Transform All Templates" button in the toolbar of Solution Explorer do what you need?

Oleg

Visual Studio 2012+ is now in `Build -> Transform All T4 Templates`

Comment: omg it's The Oleg Sych ... it you really you, right? :P ... I haven't seen that btn, as soon as I get to the office I'll look for it and try it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that for me, in VS2012, this has been moved to the Build Menu: BUILD > Transform All T4 Templates